# Xcode LLVM 6.0 Error

Tags: ios

i have problem about compile iOS default project source.
i registered apple developers site to test my app in iPhone.
after finish registration, i try to launch app but when i build LLVM 6.0 error occurred..
when create app if i select swift language, compile is successed. 
but if i select object-c "LLVM 6.0 Error" error occurred.
my dev environment is Xcode 6.1.1 / iOS 8.1.2. 
i attached my error screen shot. how can i solve..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Quit Xcode. Clean out the DerivedData folder as I explain here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247073/341994 Restart the computer.